# UWP. Microsoft Store. How do I get the base price of an Add-on with C# code?

Tags: c#, uwp

This code always returns 0.00 for different markets:

```
var listing = await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();
var price = listing.FormattedBasePrice;
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, did you associate the project with the Microsoft Store?